# How can I run a updating matplotlib graph and a updating tkinter program at once?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

So I want to run a code which uses a updating Tkinter Window and then the "results" are getting shown on a updating matplotlib graph.

I tried to just write them both normally but the one of them does not update. This is because both Windows need a kinde of "while True" loop to work.
Another thing I have tried, is to run the matplotlib plot in a different file and import the variables from the main file. But this does not work, because the code in the "plot file" just runs the code in the "main file" and does not run its own code.

A simple example:

Main file (main_test):

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from time import sleep

square_id = []
numberofsquares = 0
numberofsquares_list = []
time = 0
time_list = []

def create_window(color, title, height, width):
    global c, window, HEIGHT, WIDTH
    HEIGHT = height
    WIDTH  = width
    window = Tk()
    window.title(title)
    c = Canvas (window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg=color)
    c.pack()

def create_squares():
    global numberofsquares
    numberofsquares = numberofsquares + 1
    x = randint(0, HEIGHT)
    y = randint(0, WIDTH)
    square = c.create_rectangle(0,0,30, 30, fill='red')
    square_id.append(square)
    c.move(square, x, y)



create_window('white', 'test', 500, 500)

while True:
    time_list.append(time)
    time = time + 1
    window.update()
    for i in range(randint(0, 3)):
        create_squares()
    sleep(0.1)
    numberofsquares_list.append(numberofsquares)
```

Plot file:

```
from main_test import numberofsquares_list, time_list
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation



def animate(i):
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(numberofsquares_list, time_list)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

So here if I run the Plot file, it just runs the Main file and the Matplotlib Window never opens.

Do you know of any way to fix this issue?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `while True` or `time.sleep` in a gui application.  Both procedures cause the gui to freeze forcing you to use unnecessary methods like `window.update()`.

Your `while True` loop could just as easily be implemented using scheduled callbacks. This will allow you to call the mainloop method as well so that you can truly hand control over to the GUI.

You should also learn to use `classes` to avoid having to deal with global variables which are error prone and difficult to read.

To answer your question though, one way you can update the plot while continuing to keep the gui in motion would be to run the plot in a separate thread.

See inline comments below for more details.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import threading

class Thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = window

    def animate(self, i):
        plt.cla()
        plt.plot(window.numberofsquares_list, window.time_list)

    def run(self): 
        # the run method gets automatically triggered when you start the thread
        FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), self.animate, interval=3000)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()

class Window(Tk):  # the window class is your window
    # the __init__ method is essentially the same as your create window function
    def __init__(self, color, title, width, height):  
        super().__init__()  
        self.square_id = []  # make all your global variables class attributes
        self.numberofsquares = 0
        self.numberofsquares_list = []
        self.time = 0
        self.time_list = []
        self.height = height
        self.width  = width
        self.title(title)
        self.c = Canvas (self, width=width, height=height, bg=color)
        self.c.pack()
        self.create_squares()   # run the create squares at the end

    def create_squares(self):  
        # combined your create_squares function and your while loop into a single method
        self.time_list.append(self.time)  
        self.time = self.time + 1
        for _ in range(1, randint(1,20)):
            self.numberofsquares += 1
            x = randint(0, self.height)
            y = randint(0, self.width)
            square = self.c.create_rectangle(0,0,30, 30, fill='red')
            self.square_id.append(square)
            self.c.move(square, x, y)
        self.numberofsquares_list.append(self.numberofsquares)
        # this reschedules the function to run again at a random interval 
        # between half a second and 2 seconds
        self.after(randint(500,2000), self.create_squares)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window('white', 'test', 500, 500)  # create the window
    thread = Thread(window)   # create the thread passing the window as argument
    thread.start()            # start the thread
    window.mainloop()         # run the gui event loop
```